# OpenAI Whisper API error: "AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'Audio'"

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-whisper

ChatGPT API is announced with Speech-to-text Whisper api and i was so excited to give it a try. [Here's the link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text)

I have tried their sample code

```
# Note: you need to be using OpenAI Python v0.27.0 for the code below to work
import openai

audio_file= open("/path/to/file/audio.mp3", "rb")
```

and got the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'Audio'
```

I'm sure i'm using the version 0.27.0

```
pip list | grep openai
openai                0.27.0
```

Do you think openai is not updated yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possible reasons why you get `AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'Audio'`.

#### Reason 1: You didn't upgrade Python

The required Python version is `3.7.1` or newer, as stated in the official [OpenAI GitHub repository](https://github.com/openai/openai-python#requirements).

#### Reason 2: You didn't upgrade the OpenAI Python package

First, check your OpenAI package version by running the following command in the terminal:

```
pip show openai
```

**You need to use version `0.27.0` or newer if you want to use the OpenAI Whisper API.**

If you have an older package, run the following command in the terminal to update the OpenAI package:

```
pip install --upgrade openai
```

#### Reason 3: Your code isn't correct

Try the code below.

**OPTION 1 (recommended):**

**test.py**

```
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

audio_file = open('audio.mp3', 'rb')
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe('whisper-1', audio_file)
```

**OPTION 2:**

**test.py**

```
import openai

openai.api_key = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

audio_file = open('audio.mp3', 'rb')
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe('whisper-1', audio_file)
```

Comment: I'm using 3.10.7

Comment: I edited my answer. You have two options, but I recommend you to use the first one. Pick the second one only for testing purposes.

Comment: having the same issue. Didn't manage to solve so far. Just importing openai lib boomm! How did you solve it ?

Comment: @ThiagoC.SVentura Can you please check the OpenAI package version you're using? Use the `pip show openai` command.

Comment: I'm using python 3.8.10 and openai 1.1.1, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

While I was also facing this issue and and while I was trying to upgrade openai version i.e.`0.27.0` by 
`pip install --upgrade openai` it wasn't really upgrading. 
So for that you can just following :

```
pip uninstall openai
pip install openai==0.27.0
```

So just we have to specify its version for install nothing much